# Windows Server 2003 R2 as Fileserver is not available in network

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, file-server, shares

we are operating a Windows Server 2003 R2. After a restart the server with its shares is reachable via unc and ip (e.g. \\ws\folder1 or \\10.18.2.3\folder1). That works for at least 5 minutes after a restart. I have checked the firewall, AV is turned off and some other services that are running on this machine. I have also checked the raid, which seems ok. What's curious is that I can ping the server all the time and RDP works fine through network. It all happened yesterday suddenly. The Server runs for years without a problem. Does anyone have a clue?

I checked the eventlog and discovered following warning: NetShareEnum, 0x80070842, The Server service is not started.

The server from itself is also not reachable via \\server\

Comment: You definitly need to add more details for anyone to help you.
Anything in the eventlog? Are the important services running (e.g. server service ), what happens if you restart the server service etc.
Can you reach the server from itself \\localhost\share?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say what exactly the problem is by looking at it. It could be services related to File Server, DFS (if deployed), an Antivirus solution (if deployed, especially Symantec is known to create problems. You must backup settings and completely disable or uninstall and try again), search services, dfs flags. Also make sure there are no issues with name/address resolution and arp cache. If you suspect it is service, first check:

- "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SrmSvc\Settings" registry keys.
- You have to check whether DisableSearchDfs=1. If it is 1, make it 0 and check again. Make sure to reboot and test again.
- Additinally, check the service log and follow [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924035) KB. If the event log indicates this condition as positive, please follow the suggestions.
- Please note that you may not be able to restart the server service and it may fail. Also, if there is a critical problem, registry modification, if lead you to an issue, you need to boot from safe mode and reset the setting.

Comment: If you encounter other issues such as replication problems, you have to first identify the errors and let us know. Other considerations (non-relevant): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977381/en-us